# Database Connected But Data is not Inserted Into it

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

```
<?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales", "root", "");

function e_type($connect) {
    $output1 = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM elimo_type ORDER BY type ASC";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $output1 .= '<option value="' . $row["type"] . '">' . $row["type"] . '</option>';
    }
    return $output1;
}

function hw_type($connect) {
    $output2 = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hw_version ORDER BY type ASC";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $output2 .= '<option value="' . $row["type"] . '">' . $row["type"] . '</option>';
    }
    return $output2;
}

function sw_type($connect) {
    $output3 = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sw_version ORDER BY type ASC";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $output3 .= '<option value="' . $row["type"] . '">' . $row["type"] . '</option>';
    }
    return $output3;
}
?>
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<div class="container">
    <h3 align="center">Purchase</h3>
    <br />
    <h4 align="center">Enter Purchase Details</h4>
    <br />
    <form method="post" id="insert_form">
        <div class="table-repsonsive">
            <span id="error"></span>
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Serial No</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Hardware Version</th>
                    <th>Software Version</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="serial_no[]" class="form-control serial_no" /></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="e_type[]" class="form-control e_type"><option value="">Select Type</option><?php echo e_type($connect); ?></select></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="hw_type[]" class="form-control hw_type"><option value="">Select Hardware Version</option><?php echo hw_type($connect); ?></select></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="sw_type[]" class="form-control sw_type"><option value="">Select Software Version</option><?php echo sw_type($connect); ?></select></td>';

            html += '<td><input type="text" name="key[]" class="form-control key" /></td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
            $('#item_table').append(html);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        $('#insert_form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var error = '';
            $('.serial_no').each(function () {
                var count = 1;
                if ($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    error += "<p>Enter Serial no at " + count + " Row</p>";
                    return false;
                }
                count = count + 1;
            });

            $('.e_type').each(function () {
                var count = 1;
                if ($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    error += "<p>Select Type at " + count + " Row</p>";
                    return false;
                }
                count = count + 1;
            });

            $('.hw_type').each(function () {
                var count = 1;
                if ($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    error += "<p>Select Hardware Version  at " + count + " Row</p>";
                    return false;
                }
                count = count + 1;
            });

            $('.sw_type').each(function () {
                var count = 1;
                if ($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    error += "<p>Select Software Version  at " + count + " Row</p>";
                    return false;
                }
                count = count + 1;
            });

            $('.key').each(function () {
                var count = 1;
                if ($(this).val() == '')
                {
                    error += "<p>Enter Key at " + count + " Row</p>";
                    return false;
                }
                count = count + 1;
            });
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            if (error == '')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "insert.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if (data == 'ok')
                        {
                            $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                            $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Purchase Details Saved</div>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
            {
                $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<?php
//insert.php;

if (isset($_POST["serial_no"])) {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales", "root", "");
    $id = uniqid();
    for ($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["serial_no"]); $count++) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO elimo_purchase 
      (id,serial_no, e_type, hw_type, sw_type,key) 
      VALUES (:id,:serial_no, :e_type, :hw_type, :sw_type,:key)";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':serial_no' => $_POST["serial_no"][$count],
                    ':e_type' => $_POST["e_type"][$count],
                    ':hw_type' => $_POST["hw_type"][$count],
                    ':sw_type' => $_POST["sw_type"][$count],
                    ':key' => $_POST["key"][$count]
                )
        );
    }
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if (isset($result)) {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm getting output as purchase details saved but result is not stored into database.

Comment: You can't use `fetchAll()` for an `INSERT` statement, it can only be used with `SELECT`.

Comment: You don't need to prepare the statement inside the loop. Prepare it once, then call `execute()` in a loop with different parameter arrays.

Comment: To tell if the `INSERT` was successful, check the return value of `$statement->execute()`

Comment: please explain through code

Comment: functions contain select statement

Comment: I was talking about the code in `insert.php`, not `index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to debug as per below,

1. Check all the values which you pass in insert query print all and check values.
2. Then print the query and fire the same query manually and check it was inserted or not

Answer (score -1):

When you're doing an `INSERT` query, you can't use a `fetch` function, because it doesn't return any data. That can only be used with `SELECT`. You need to check the result of `$statement->execute()`.

```
if(isset($_POST["serial_no"]))
{
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales", "root", "");
    $id = uniqid();
    $query = "INSERT INTO elimo_purchase (id,serial_no, e_type, hw_type, sw_type,key) 
              VALUES (:id,:serial_no, :e_type, :hw_type, :sw_type,:key)";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["serial_no"]); $count++)
    {  
        if (!$statement->execute(
                array(
                    ':id'   => $id,
                    ':serial_no'   => $_POST["serial_no"][$count],
                    ':e_type'  => $_POST["e_type"][$count], 
                    ':hw_type' => $_POST["hw_type"][$count], 
                    ':sw_type' => $_POST["sw_type"][$count], 
                    ':key'  => $_POST["key"][$count]
                    )
                )) {
            die('not ok');
        }
    }
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: nope now it is not working at all.

Comment: e_type,hw_type and sw_type are data of another table

Comment: I thought they come from the form in `index.php`.